# js If you add numbers with Math.ceil, they are +1

Tags: javascript, typescript

We added two values using Math.ceil.
One became 50 when I used Math.ceil, and the other became 80 when I used Math.ceil.
For some reason, when I add 50 and 80, the result is 131.

```
console.log(Math.ceil(e.currentTarget.clientHeight)  // 50
console.log(Math.ceil(e.currentTarget.scrollTop)) // 80
console.log(Math.ceil(e.currentTarget.clientHeight) + Math.ceil(e.currentTarget.scrollTop)); // 131
```

status of implementation
e.currentTarget.clientHeight // 50
e.currentTarget.scrollTop  // 80.1111145019531

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: `Math.ceil(50) + Math.ceil(80)` gives me 130. What are the actual values before you `Math.ceil` them?

Comment: if you do `var height = e.currentTarget.clientHeight, top = e.currentTarget.scrollTop` - then use those variables instead ... does it still happen?

Comment: Added the actual values

Comment: Guess what `Math.ceil(80.11111...)` is.

Comment: “On systems using display scaling, scrollTop may give you a decimal value.”
([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop))

Comment: To answer @tadman  and to provide awareness ofyour outcome - Math.ceil(80.1111145019531) = 81... .therefore when added to the 50 from the other value - gives you 131... I would have thought it was obvious that one of the values was a fraction above the 50 or 80.... and knowing what Math.ceil() does - its obvious that one of the values was kicking up to the next integer. Some research / inspecting the element / awareness of basic JS would have resolved this in an instant. Sorry to be blunt - but this is obvious as to the cause and resolution of the issue.

Comment: Maybe you're looking for `Math.floor()`. As a reminder, the floor is the flat thing *under* you, and the ceiling is that flat thing *over* you.

Comment: Using Math.Floor, I got 1 less.

Comment: If I don't add the two and look at them one at a time in console, it shows 50,80. However, when I add the two together, the result is 129.

Comment: I don't know why the numbers don't add up to the correct number,

Comment: that's maybe because one of these values has a fraction. for example Math.ceil(50.004) is 51 and when you add 80 to it, it becomes 131.

Comment: I'm sorry. I finally understand!
I'm going to make a new question, because I want to ask it a little differently.

Comment: @ryuuw usually it's better to do rounding (`Math.round()`), ceiling, or floor operations after you get a final result. However, even then things can be very complicated. There are college-level classes in how to do scientific calculations with computer math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Math.ceil(80.1111145019531) = 81`

Thus the sum is 131. `Math.ceil` always rounds up.

Comment: more of a comment than a solution?